# Output all variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am simply trying to output all of the parameters passed to a variadic function template. I tried this recursive approach:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename TFirst, typename... Arguments>
void Output(TFirst first, Arguments... parameters)
{
  std::cout << first << std::endl;
  Output(parameters);
}

template<typename TFirst>
void Output(TFirst first)
{
  std::cout << first << std::endl;
}

void Output()
{
  // do nothing
}

int main()
{
  Output(1.0f, 2);
}
```

but I get `parameter packs not expanded with '...'`. Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

--------- EDIT ------------

Here is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
inline void showArguments(T&& arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; }

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
inline void showArguments(First&& first, Rest&& ...rest)
{
  showArguments(first);
  showArguments(rest...);
}

int main()
{
    showArguments("Hello", "World", 1, 2.3, false, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
template<typename TFirst, typename... Arguments>
void Output(TFirst first, Arguments... parameters)
{
  std::cout << first << std::endl;
  Output(parameters...);
}
```

(note the trailing ... after the parameters)